# lipschitz constant of a multivariate function

Tags: convex-optimization, global-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-algebra, fa.functional-analysis

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{50} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I need to compute the Lipschitz constant of $f$ to solve an optimization problem using a specific algorithm. Does any one have suggestions on how to estimate such Lipschitz constants?

Suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than compute "the" Lipschitz constant, it is much easier to do a *backtracking line search* that roughly upper-bounds the Lipschitz constant.

To get some ideas, on how one might do a simple line-search, search google for "line search", "backtracking line search" and the ilk, and you'll find several useful ideas.